# OWD Sharing Settings and Account Sharing Rule

Tags: security, sharing, owd, visibility

I'm unable to get this working in my companies Sandbox so I've spun up a brand new Developer Edition Org to see if I can replicate the issue.  Being a brand new org there are no permission sets, territory management, etc.

I'm using the Standard Profile for my Test User

I've set the OWD Default for ACCOUNT to be PRIVATE
When I logged in as Test User I was able to confirm they could NOT see the Account records
I created a sharing rule whereby all Account Records owned by the Role and Subordinates was shared to a Public Group called "read only"
I made the Test User a member of the Public Group called "read only"
I checked the Sharing Hierarchy of the Account record and confirmed that the public group called "read only" had read only access and nothing more
I logged in as the Test User and discovered they have EDIT Rights to the Account Record.

The USE CASE I'm trying to solve is this.

1. Make a standard object like Account have default access of Private via OWD Sharing Settings
2. Share out access to a limited number of users via Public Groups to have READ ONLY access to a standard object like Account
3. When administering Users in the future add them to the relevant Public Groups when creating their User Account thus automatically giving them the current level of PRIVATE, READ or READ/WRITE Access.

Implicit Sharing doesn't come into this because the Account Record is the parent object.

Just to emphasise this is a brand new Org and all I did was as listed above.  There is no legacy configuration to get in the way.  I'd be curious to see if others can repliate this behaviour in their Orgs too.

Thank you

Comment: When you say edit rights you mean you were able to edit and save or just see edit button?

Comment: I think you've found the answer.  I have an EDIT button and I can go into edit mode by double clicking a field but when I goto Save the error message is "Oops...you don't have the necessary privileges to edit this record.  See your administrator for help.

Comment: @manjit5190 please post your answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Salesforce is behaving correctly. The edit button is usually visible when you have EDIT access on the object, but record level security is applied on runtime.

So even if you see the edit button, once you try to edit and save, you should see an error.

Comment: This is correct but in further testing on other objects I did notice the Interface behaving differently.  On some objects when clicking the Edit button a pop up appeared advising you can not edit the record. On the whole though the error message appears when clicking save.